# Not able to create conda environment in SageMaker studio

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-sagemaker

Sagemaker studio terminal shows default python version as "Python 3.7.10"
I am trying to create conda environment with python3.9 version as below.

```
conda create --name custom_python_39 python=3.9
```

But I get the following error:

RemoveError: 'setuptools' is a dependency of conda and cannot be removed from
conda's operating environment.

But pip list doesn't show setuptools.

I already tried the following

```
conda update conda -n base
conda update --force conda
```

But I get the following erros:
bash-4.2$ conda update conda -n base
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: /
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

```
  - conda-forge/noarch::pyopenssl==22.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::requests==2.27.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::urllib3==1.26.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::argon2-cffi==21.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defaults/linux-64::argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0=py37h7f8727e_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::bleach==3.1.4=pyh9f0ad1d_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::brotlipy==0.7.0=py37h5e8e339_1001
  - conda-forge/linux-64::conda==4.6.14=py37_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::ipykernel==5.2.0=py37h43977f1_1
  - conda-forge/linux-64::ipython==7.13.0=py37hc8dfbb8_2
  - conda-forge/linux-64::jedi==0.16.0=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::jinja2==2.11.3=pyhd8ed1ab_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::jsonschema==3.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_3
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbconvert==5.6.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
  - conda-forge/noarch::notebook==6.4.1=pyha770c72_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::prompt-toolkit==3.0.5=py_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::pygments==2.6.1=py_0
/ Killed
```

Comment: I'm able to create the conda env. on both the system and image terminal. Can you try creating the environment on an Image terminal (for example, a data science image)? If you create it on the system terminal, you won't be able to use the env. in notebooks.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am not using notebook for my development.  I am using studio as IDE. Hence I am trying to create via terminal as I am intending to create venv and execute my python script as  "python main.py" from the terminal.

Comment: Please change the title to "conda" not "condo". Did you get anywhere with the solution?